# Make the placeholder float up to display as label when user focuses on <lightning-input>

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, css

Is there any way to make a placeholder to float up and display as a Label for  when a user clicks on or types on the field in LWC.

Something like in the below link
https://codepen.io/devesh8/pen/MWYEJEP

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is trivial to convert.

First, we change the event handlers that set the attribute:

```
onclick={setValue} onchange={setValue}
```

```
  setValue(event) {
    event.target.setAttribute('value', event.target.value);
  }
```

Next, we compile the SCSS to CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}
.did-floating-label-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.did-floating-label {
  color: #1e4c82;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 15px;
  top: 11px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
.did-floating-input, .did-floating-select {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #323840;
  border: 1px solid #3D85D8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.did-floating-input:focus, .did-floating-select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.did-floating-input:focus ~ .did-floating-label, .did-floating-select:focus ~ .did-floating-label {
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
select.did-floating-select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
select.did-floating-select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
.did-floating-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .did-floating-label {
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.did-floating-select:not([value=""]):valid ~ .did-floating-label {
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.did-floating-select[value=""]:focus ~ .did-floating-label {
  top: 11px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.did-floating-select:not([multiple]):not([size]) {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='6' viewBox='0 0 8 6'%3E%3Cpath id='Path_1' data-name='Path 1' d='M371,294l4,6,4-6Z' transform='translate(-371 -294)' fill='%23003d71'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
  background-position: right 15px top 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.did-error-input .did-floating-input, .did-error-input .did-floating-select {
  border: 2px solid #9d3b3b;
  color: #9d3b3b;
}
.did-error-input .did-floating-label {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #9d3b3b;
}
.did-error-input .did-floating-select:not([multiple]):not([size]) {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='6' viewBox='0 0 8 6'%3E%3Cpath id='Path_1' data-name='Path 1' d='M371,294l4,6,4-6Z' transform='translate(-371 -294)' fill='%239d3b3b'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}
.input-group {
  display: flex;
}
.input-group .did-floating-input {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.input-group-append {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*   margin-left:-1px; */
}
.input-group-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 34px;
  color: #323840;
  padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #3D85D8;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-right: none;
}
```

And that's it.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/salesforce-lwc-uynegt?title=LWC%20playground).

Comment: The above code will work for <input> tag, is there any way to make it work for <lightning-input> tag?

Comment: @DilipanManoharan No, it's not possible.